# Gdm3 doesn't start after upgrading system

Tags: debian, gdm, gdm3

I installed Debian a few days ago. The first thing I did was install the ATI graphics driver (I needed some additional software to install it) and some apps for everyday use.

Today I upgraded the system and now `gdm3` doesn't start. In recovery mode the system works, but when I try to run X (`startx`), everything is like in normal mode.

How can I get my system working again?

Comment: Can you look at the logs? They should be at `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`. Please use a pasting service to paste the logs.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/6yBxWrG2

Comment: Seems like your X is starting up fine. What happens if you try to run gdm3 directly?

Comment: Try uninstalling the fglrx driver, it should work again.